# android imagebutton answers and imageview questions

Tags: android

I am stuck. Basically I am doing a multiple choice type of thing where I have 10 imagebuttons all assigned with images from an array of images, these are the answers. Then I have an imageview which I want to have 10 images come up which are image questions loaded into another array. So basically I have 20 images total, 10 images in an array which are questions, and 10 images in an array that are answers. I want to display to the user all the imagebuttons and then have the user answer the imageview questions one at a time and display something like "correct!" on the screen when they are answered correctly and record some data possibly and also display "incorrect" when they are answered incorrectly and record some data possibly too. So my problem is I cannot figure out a good way to do this. Can anyone help me out? Possibly guide me?

A good thing to know about these arrays for example is that the answerimagesarray[2] is the answer to questionsimagesarray[2] and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to show all the questions & answers at the same time, and get them to match these up? Or when they click one question, does it pop up with a list of all the possible answers?

Comment: I will show all 10 answers at the entire time. Then I want the 10 questions to pop up individually, and after they are answered display correct or incorrect, and then move on to display the next question. Each of the 10 answers is an answer to ONE of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have one ImageView that you change each time any of the buttons are clicked. You will need to store: all of your drawable IDs in an Integer[] imageDrawableIds for the images for the ImageView, another Integer[] buttonDrawableIds for the pictures for the buttons, and an int index to keep track of which image is currently showing in the ImageView.

Extend the ImageButton class to have the button save its index (from 0 to 9) and make a method to get it. This will help later, and makes it easy to make the buttons in a loop if you save the pictures for them in an array that corresponds to the index (as suggested above.)

Make an OnClickListener and set it to each of the 10 ImageButtons so you can handle any of the 10 ImageButtons being clicked.. In the onClick(View v) method, get which index was chosen by ((MyImageButtonClassName)v).getIndex(). With that you can display a message depending on if that value equals the index of the image in the ImageView. Then set your ImageView to the next image: imageViewName.setImageResource(imageDrawableIds[index++]) where the variables are defined above in the first paragraph.

Hope this is what you are looking for. Feel free to hit me up for more help.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the response. I am a complete beginner at android and java, I used to know c++ a few years ago... so all this that you said is a little confusing but I'm going to try and get it straight, and tell me if I'm wrong. I believe I have stored the drawable IDs, for example, part of my code is answersimagesarray[]

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the response. I am a complete beginner at android and java, I used to know c++ a few years ago... so all this that you said is a little confusing but I'm going to try and get it straight, and tell me if I'm wrong. I believe I have stored the drawable IDs, for example, part of my code is int[] answersimagesarray = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2.....and so on}. Can you explain more to me the purpose of these indexes and how I would use them? I am trying to figure it all out by writing it out but I am not sure if I am getting anywhere

Comment: Join a chat and I can walk you through it. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7211/help-teaching

Comment: Hey it says I need 20 reputation in order to chat...but i would really like your help...how can I boost my reputation?

Comment: Eh not really sure I checked to see if I could give you some but I can't. Hit me up with your email and we can discuss over that.

Comment: how can i give you my email? in these comments? a private message?